# Typescript - How to map enum/tuple to object?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, zod

I'm trying to convert an enum to a map type using various existing configs to hydrate a typescript type. I've create a [ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcDkyEAJvgNwBQFApgB6SxzUB2ArngIIAKAkgNLUAngGdEFOHGDE4AXgI9SAGnFMQAQ2AAbWQQCi6rfmUTmakNR34AcmepGVa4sSjVhoufg5OXb+2koUAMYQzMLwjs6uwgDKgQAW1Oo6yAB0EABGAFbUgTAAFAgqgcAwggBcKClhUMDMAOZ5AJTGcMGszDBQ5ZXVtQ3NKpBhapoAwiTUFam99U0twzCTPZ19cyrV1NQwU1UrswNojQHBofDcPABiwNSaxOPMmMB1OoUSANrnAiIpUgC6OzN+i0PrwvsIUokNJp-ssavtgZ8hODTOYYdM9kCVCD+EiUhEfMIYfiorEEuplP4qJh2rlgCE4HUtqTIQB5LI5GAAHjBTFoi2YxFEiJEb1+AD48ikpQBrJEVMGNCpcYCBaWc0pgagQTBwc5XG53EKPOqKOBgt5sEDpahQcViCQAegdcAAKgksBBNJoIAB3PpwTS1CzECCuDpwH3QaUqFwwVhQZhwWXfFzEViBah5PJgFwAN1NgXjjVkYrgBSlKRz1HzcDehdtFT111u92Ndfjv0OpoQh0oaCoJzCkmYYFY21rwvBUlNk4hBmhOmxYJ+xBnoNxkK0v0og-gwnirPZuR0jJgzPUbOyuUlUtqo5gRyCISHYDUsGAI3PamSaSP+X3ZJqJeHKNBQGoWLG8bMC6giaj+tSYDa6qwVqOqvu+n4HuoYoBEAA) to try to fully illustrate what I'm trying to do.

I have an enum:

```
export enum APIKeys {
  id = 'Id',
  email = 'Email',
  name = 'Name',
  address = 'Address',
};
```

And the following config:

```
const addressSchema = z.object({
  city: z.string(),
  country: z.string(),
  postalCode: z.string(),
  state: z.string(),
  street: z.string(),
});

const APIFieldConfig = {
  [APIKeys.id]: z.string(),
  [APIKeys.email]: z.string(),
  [APIKeys.name]: z.string(),
  [APIKeys.address]: addressSchema,
};
```

I have the following function:

```
function getSchemaObject<Keys extends APIKeys[]>(...keys: Keys): Pick<typeof APIFieldConfig, Keys[number]> {
  // The following line doesnt work because it erases the types?
  return keys.reduce((prev, cur) => ({...prev, [cur]: APIFieldConfig[cur]}), {});
}
```

Whats the best way to implement the function in a way that preserves the types and doesn't create errors?

[ts playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbzgLzgXzgMyhEcDkyEAJvgNwBQFApgB6SxzUB2ArngIIAKAkgNLUAngGdEFOHGDE4AXgI9SAGnFMQAQ2AAbWQQCi6rfmUTmakNR34AcmepGVa4sSjVhoufg5OXb+2koUAMYQzMLwjs6uwgDKgQAW1Oo6yAB0EABGAFbUgTAAFAgqgcAwggBcKClhUMDMAOZ5AJTGcMGszDBQ5ZXVtQ3NKpBhapoAwiTUFam99U0twzCTPZ19cyrV1NQwU1UrswNojQHBofDcPABiwNSaxOPMmMB1OoUSANrnAiIpUgC6OzN+i0PrwvsIUokNJp-ssavtgZ8hODTOYYdM9kCVCD+EiUhEfMIYfiorEEuplP4qJh2rlgCE4HUtqTIQB5LI5GAAHjBTFoi2YxFEiJEb1+AD48ikpQBrJEVMGNCpcYCBaWc0pgagQTBwc5XG53EKPOqKOBgt5sEDpahQcViCQAegdcAAKgksBBNJoIAB3PpwTS1CzECCuDpwH3QaUqFwwVhQZhwWXfFzEViBah5PJgFwAN1NgXjjVkYrgBSlKRz1HzcDehdtFT111u92Ndfjv0OpoQh0oaCoJzCkmYYFY21rwvBUlNk4hBmhOmxYJ+xBnoNxkK0v0og-gwnirPZuR0jJgzPUbOyuUlUtqo5gRyCISHYDUsGAI3PamSaSP+X3ZJqJeHKNBQGoWLG8bMC6giaj+tSYDa6qwVqOqvu+n4HuoYoBEAA)

Comment: Does using a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wR1e1W) answer your question? If so, I can write it as one with some explanation (ref: [1](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-4.html#const-assertions), [2](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/enums.html#objects-vs-enums)). If not, what did I miss?

Comment: I think my hope is to generate the object values without using type assertions. Is that not possible?

Comment: I've edited this to add the zod tag.  If you don't think that's accurate please [edit] to remove the zod dependency in the example. Good luck!

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77737914/typescript-how-to-map-enum-tuple-to-object?noredirect=1#comment137051474_77737914) @tallowen AFAIK, TS's [control flow analysis](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9998) isn't yet capable of such inferences.

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77737914/typescript-how-to-map-enum-tuple-to-object?noredirect=1#comment137052143_77737914) In any case: unless you're actually doing something with the intermediate `schemaObject`, you can just use Zod's [`pick`](https://zod.dev/?id=pickomit) method directly, or some [abstraction](https://tsplay.dev/mb1rbN) over it if you absolutely need bare tuple input. Let me know how to proceed if you'd like to see an answer based on either of those playground links.